# Owin WebApi 2 - Decrypting an OAuth Key on a seperate platform

Tags: encryption, asp.net-web-api, oauth

We have a WebAPI 2 project that is using OAuth2 provider in OWIN/Katana in production.

Is it possible to be able to provide the token that is generated to another platform which doesn't run this same API so that they are able to decrypt the token and extract the claims? Obviously the machine keys would need to be in sync; but has anyone got any experience of this?

I'm not 100% sold on doing this yet, as i'm a firm believer in having a single authorisation server, however feedback is appreciated and whether this is indeed a mistep or not.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the tumbleweed has spoken :)